# Two tables side by side, fill remaining width

Tags: html, css

I have two tables. The left table should have an auto width so that its flexible based on its contents. The right table I need to fill the remaining width of the containing div.

I understand that I can do this by setting `table.b` to `display: block`, but the problem with this is that it has no effect in IE9 and below. I need a solution that works down to IE6 (or as close as possible).

```css
table.a {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}

table.b {
    background-color: red;
    /* display: block; Can't do display block because setting table as block on <= IE 9 doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<table class="a">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello1</td><td>Test1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="b">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello2</td><td>This table should fill remaining width</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Down to IE6! I feel for you, I really do.

Comment: @GeorgeLee Tell me about it! For the sake of the question whoever can get nearest to IE6 would be fine and I can try and go further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution would help you,

Wrap each''s with separate ''s. Make the left table wrapper '.table1' as float left and right table wrapper '.table2' as overflow hidden. Tada!!

https://jsfiddle.net/raaj_obuli/jt71ywwm/1/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.table1 {
   float: left;
  background: #bbb;
}
.table2 {
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #afa;
}
```

```html
<div class="table1">
<table class="a" >
    <tr>
        <td>Hello1</td><td>Test1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="table2">
<table class="b" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello2</td><td>This table should fill remaining width</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @obuliraj! This works perfectly. Karthi, he changed the code, this isn't a copy of anything.

Comment: But anyway, I was provide a clue to find solution, He didn't start from the scratch...?

Comment: @KarthiKeyan, Firstly, sorry about taking your snippet. I was clear about the solution for problem. Wrapping the table with div and bla! bla! bla! I just wanted provide the solution quickly. So, I reused your code. But it is not that I copied your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put display block directly to the table just add div around the table and float the div
Try this Sample it may works for you

`here`http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPBbrW

Comment: Thanks for the JavaScript solution, but I think that this can be accomplished using purely `HTML` and `CSS`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't actually work on IE 9 and below so it's not achieving anything.